# How to change values in multiple pandas dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a dataframe like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRve5.png).

I want to normalize the data in the 'cholesterol' and 'gluc' columns, such that if the value is 1 then it becomes 0, and if it's greater than 1 then it becomes 1 (basically 0 is always good and 1 is always bad). I can do this to each column individually with `np.where()`, however I'm curious if there's a way to change both columns with a single command, but I haven't found anything related online.

I can start by slicing the columns with `df.loc[:, ['cholesterol', 'gluc']]`, which creates a view of the two columns. Is there a way to change this view with one command or do I still have to change each column individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
df.loc[:, ['cholesterol', 'gluc']] = np.where(df.loc[:, ['cholesterol', 'gluc']] > 1, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with the binarize function from sklearn library.
Not a one line but almost

`https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.binarize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.binarize`

It would be something like this

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import binarize
binarizer = preprocessing.Binarizer(0.0).fit(df)
output = binarizer.transform(X)
```

More info here

`https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-binarization`